# <tr>'s aren't making new rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

For some reason my table rows aren't spacing out properly, but merely overlaying new rows on old ones. Instead of a 2-row table, I've got what looks like a 1-row table with 2 rows overlaid on each other. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
<table id="points-list-wrapper">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="name">Test</p>
            <p class="amount">597<img class="icon"src="icon.png"></img></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="name">Another test!</p>
            <p class="amount">0<img class="icon"src="icon.png"></img></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the relevant css...

```
#points-list-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:20%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:auto;
    width:50%;
    border:5px solid white;
}
td {
    height:100px;
}
tr {
    height:100px;
}
```

And the end result is that the table rows are overlapping, as though they were `position:absolute`.

The table itself is positioned absolutely, but that should not affect the rows within it, right? What am I missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you screenshot overlapping problem? i try your code on jsfiddle and problem not found.

Comment: Works as expected in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/tn1qvf3k/. Note `img` is self closing, you'll see its highlited in the fiddle. You don't need `</img>` . What browser are you seeing the problem in,

Comment: your code seems to render fine (just remove closing `img` tags) ... https://jsfiddle.net/Ldprsrdv/

Comment: Here's a fiddle where i copied in my full source code. https://jsfiddle.net/hdsbgsu9/

Comment: See all that red in your fiddle? You have invalid code. See `id="main-wrapper""` note the 2 sets of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely positioning everything inside your table cells. Absolute positioning works of the nearest `relative` positioned ancestor.

Change `.td` to:

```
td {
  height: 100px;
  position:relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hdsbgsu9/1/

Basic position tutorial: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Make sure you fix all your other invalid html issues.